# Does MMS messages with pictures always use your data?

Tags: applications, sms, mms

I have the Pixel 3a running android 11. My Wi-Fi is always on. And my mobile data is always off. I have the app "My Data Manager" installed so I can see when my mobile data is being used. When I send an MMS text, no data is used. But when I send a MMS text with a pic, then I can see that my data is being used. The following app is using the data "org.codeaurora.ims". Is this normal? Because my phone plan is supposed to offer unlimited text messaging with pictures. But everytime I send an MMS text with a pic, it's eating away at my data plan. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, MMS are sent via regular data connection, however as MMS already have a price of it's own the MNOs should not charge the use data for it.

Comment: Thank you Robert.  So this is not an issue with Android but an issue I need to resolve with my phone carrier?  I don't know what MNO stands for.

Comment: MNO = Mobile Network Operator

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not take your data(Internet connection) but it takes the balance of your sim.